# How could i remove dropdown after clicking outside in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to remove the dropdown after clicking outside the button. How could i implement this using react native. I tried with using ref but its not supporting.

```js
const useOutsideClick = (ref, callback) => {
  const handleClick = e => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      callback();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: What you could do is, create a full width and height backdrop when you open the dropdown, and assign a onClick on it to remove or close the dropdown

Comment: do you mean reactjs?

Comment: no react native